# Image Component Linking Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, tridion

I have a embedded component in Tridion which has Image field(named leadImage). Using a customized popup i want to link a Image in this Image field(leadImage). Is it possible? This has to be done with clicking on "Save" event of the component and hence mainly jquery/javascript.

The image to be linked is already in the CMS system. It will be created by default by doing some other action in customized popup. I will have the tcmid/image name etc for the Image.

Not able to find much documentation on Anguilla Api to help me achieve this.

Comment: Sorry your question is not very clear to me, what do you mean by embedded component? Please elaborate more.

Comment: Anyway, there are a lot of examples on how to create custom popups and listen for "save" events on Domain Model items.

Comment: Do you want to force people to add an image in this field? That's what I am understanding when reading your question. Is it a text field? Multimedia Component link? I am not sure having the tag "JavaScript" will help you out at all in this question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it's possible to override the 'insert component' button in the SDL Tridion GUI using the Anguilla framework.

There are tonnes of posts out there about the anquilla framework... i'd recommend this one http://albertromkes.com/2012/01/30/tridion-gui-extensions-how-to-load-a-javascript-without-showing-a-gui-element/ to show you how to inject your own javascript into a specific 'view'

To override the insert component button you simply remove the event handler:

```
// remove the default insert behavior which is to open up the item select dialog
$log.message("Removing handlers for the insert event");
$evt.removeAllEventHandlers(fieldBuilder, "insert");
```

Then you can put your own functionality on there by adding your own event handler:

```
// add our own insert behavior
$log.message("Adding a custom handler for the insert event");
$evt.addEventHandler(fieldBuilder, "insert", function(event) {
  // whatever it is you wish to do :)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks John for the quick response. This is exactly what i was looking for. 
var imageField = fieldBuilder.getField("lead_image");

Comment: Great, then can you accept my answer? this gives me points and lets other know this was the correct solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume an "embedded component" to be a `Component Link` allowing `Multimedia Links` or possibly a `Multimedia Link` itself (in schema field options).

### Out-of-the-box Schema Field Defaults

Except for the fact you're creating the image with "some other action in customized popup" to set a default linked component you can:

1. Set the `Default Value` in the linked item in the schema field
2. Set the `Default` in template or rendering logic

### Relationships

Otherwise create the relationship between your images using one of a variety of approaches:

- Manually curated lists ("Link List" or "Container" components)
- "Configuration" components (key value pairs)
- Organizational items -- items within a certain folder
- Naming conventions -- items with similar names get rendered together
- Categories and Keywords (taxonomy classification)

*Authors expect to be able to control which images they link to or have them automatically added for rendering. It doesn't necessarily have to be in the component.*

### Changes and BluePrinting

While an extension for a specific field is certainly possible, there's a risk on creating this for a specific field in a specific schema field. Be sure your approach works for new components, new logic, and schema changes.

If you have a programmatic requirement to add a `leadimage`, consider placing this in template logic where it can be easily changed, across publications, across all component presentations without revisiting each component. **Also make sure your component IDs use the correct publication ID for where these components are created.**

**For example you need to handle localized versions where the tcm-id is from a lower publication than say the 020 Content publication.**

Sounds like an interesting requirement, do leave a comment on what that other action should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks John for the quick response. This is in-line with what i was looking for.

Since my field builder will have many fields i have modified the code as follows:

```
var imageField = fieldBuilder.getField("lead_image"); // Where lead_image is the name for ImageField in this component

// remove the default insert behavior which is to open up the item select dialog
$log.message("Removing handlers for the insert event");
$evt.removeAllEventHandlers(imageField "insert");

// add our own insert behavior
$log.message("Adding a custom handler for the insert event");
$evt.addEventHandler(imageField , "insert", function(event) {
}
```

In the addeventhandler will it be possible to set Title and ImageIcon as required? Unable to find it on Anquilla Api or anywhere else.

Comment: Yes it's possible to change the icon and title, i would recommend injecting a css onto the sdl tridion view, the css will contain the image details... as for the text, you'll have to remove the existing label and apply your own using JS. Perhaps you could accept my answer and ask your query as a new question so the two are not confused here... plus then I can paste some samples to help explain :)